# How to allow upload file with same name jquery.filer

Tags: jquery, jquery-filer

I am using jquery.filer plugin for file uploading purpose on my page. It is working fine but when I choose same file again to upload, it is not uploading neither it is showing any error.

This is plugin link which i am using :
http://filer.grandesign.md/

Answer (score 0):

According to [Documentation](http://filer.gradesign.md#documentation) you need to write in option:

```
allowDuplicates: false
```